# Exclude endpoints in uniform mesh

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a uniform 1D mesh with N points over an interval of reals (0, pi). Currently I have the following working code:

```
import numpy as np
u = np.linspace(0, np.pi, N+1, endpoint = False)
u = u[1:]
```

Can I avoid the last line? It seems that there is no option such as `startpoint` equivalent to `endpoint` above.

Comment: As a side note you can do `u[1:]`. Omitting the second part will imply a slice from 1 to the end and clarify your intentions some.

Comment: You could also add the `[1:]` to the end of the first line, i.e. `u = np.linspace(0, np.pi, N+1, endpoint = False)[1:]` if it is the extra line that disturbs you.

Comment: @Jaime That's clever, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
np.linspace(np.pi/(N+1), np.pi, N, endpoint = False)
```

This gives the same results as your code by calculating the first point explicitly.  I don't claim this way is better than your original code, though.